# If $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T})$. Is $[0,1]$ compact in this space?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{B}= \{[a,b] \mid a \in \Bbb Q, b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q, a< b \}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for some space $(\Bbb R, \mathcal{T})$. Is $[0,1]$ compact in this space?

If $[0,1]$ was compact, then for any open cover $\mathcal{A}$ of $[0,1]$ there should exist a finite subcover $\mathcal{A}' \subset \mathcal{A}$. I guess that the problem want me to construct an open cover that doens't admit a finite subcover.

I cannot think of anyway how to start constructing such an cover. What came to my mind was something like $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} [-1/n, \sqrt2 - 1/n]$ which should at least be a cover for $[0,1]$, but I don't have any tools to figure out whether this admits a finite subcover or not. Any tips on how to construct this kind of cover?

Answer (score 4):

Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of rational numbers greater than $\sqrt{2}-1$ and converging to $\sqrt{2}-1$. You can not extract a finite covering from the covering defined by by $I_1 = [0,\sqrt{2}-1]$ and $I_n = [a_n,\sqrt{2}]$ for $n \ge 2$. Indeed, you must select $I_1$ (it is the only interval containing $0$) and infinitely many $I_n$ with $n \ge 2$: finite union of such intervals can produce only closed sets in the usual topology, contained in $]\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: This is not a counterexample as your b are in $\mathbb Q$

Comment: @linkja Yes. I corrected to have irrational upper bounds.

Comment: but your lower bounds are irational

Comment: @linkja Yes.Now, I hope that it is right.

Comment: I don't quite get the argument that finite union of such intervals can produce only closed sets in the usual topology, contained in $]\sqrt{2}-1,\sqrt{2}]$, what do you mean by this? @ChristopheLeuridan

Comment: @SleepWalker The union of finitely many closed intervals is a closed subset.